# OpenCL – adding `float4` to `float4` array does nothing

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenGL VBO containing `cl_float4` vertices and I'm trying to update the VBO via OpenCL (I'm rendering the VBO contents as `GL_POINTS`). I pass `cl_mem` object representing the VBO as a kernel argument (the buffer is set as `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`).

**Unfortunately I cannot update one vertex's `float4` data at once.**

Following snippet doesn't work (i.e. the rendered points doesn't move):

```
__kernel void update(__global float4* particle_positions)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    particle_positions[gid] += float4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
}
```

Following snippet **does** work (i.e. the rendered points move):

```
__kernel void update(__global float4* particle_positions)
{ 
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    particle_positions[gid].x += 0.1;
    particle_positions[gid].y += 0.1;
    particle_positions[gid].z += 0.1;
}
```

Comment: (float4)(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0); not  float4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0);

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Thank you, it works! If you post this as the answer, I'll accept it. This was really a stupid question – I come from GLSL and I was (ignorantly) persuaded that OpenCL C would have the same syntax, so looking at syntax differences between GLSL and OpenCL C didn't even come to my mind.

Comment: it's not a stupid question. your post and the response will help the next guy who has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to be in paranthesis like

```
(float4)(1,1,1,1)
```

to have a float4 type. Or you can use other types too

```
(float4)((float2)(1,1),(float2)(1,1))
```

or mixed type

```
(float4)((float2)(1,1),1,1)
```

acts like an overloaded function.